# Replace html array notation var with loop value jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to replace the [2] in the name values of the hidden fields with a new value within a loop. The 2 could be any number and so I won't necessarily know it when I'm looping. What would be the best course of action in replacing it?

```
<input type="hidden" class="pid" name="t[2][p][149][id]" value="ID">
<input type="hidden" class="pane" name="t[2][p][149][name]" value="NAME">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input").each(function() {
  name = $(this).attr("name");
  name = name.replace(/^t\[\d+\]/, "t[your number]");
  $(this).attr("name", name);
});
```

Comment: From the question: *"The 2 could be any number and so I won't necessarily know it when I'm looping."*

Comment: Cool. Would also recommend not assuming all names should be processed... :-)

Comment: Still, won't work when the 'any number' has more than a single digit.

Answer (score 1):

If it will always be the patten "t[number][..." you should create a regular expression and replace it that way.

Comment: Note that he asked for "the best course of action in replacing it" not "tell me exactly how to write the code to replace it" !

Comment: Yes. But, no reason not to go above and beyond. Plus, it's much easier to work out the english from the code, than the reverse.